# Deleting rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I created a query that will delete rows from three tables that has 'Employee'.
When I execute it, it only deletes rows from one table **tblEmployeeType**. I tried adding *Alias* of other tables beside *DELETE* but SQL does not support it. Is there any alternative way of deleting rows from multiple tables? or I forgot some codes on my query or should I just separate delete queries? Thank you.

```
DELETE a
    FROM tblEmployeeType a INNER JOIN
         tbl_Selected_AccessType b
         ON a.EmpTypeName = b.UserType INNER JOIN
         tbl_AccessType_AllFunction c
         ON a.EmpTypeName = c.UserType
    WHERE a.EmpTypeName = 'Employee'`
```

Comment: If foreign key is defined between the tables, then you can use DELETE CASCADE to delete rows from these tables in single query. Or you can create a Stored Procedure with delete statements.

Because you cannot delete rows from multiple tables in single query if they are not related.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements can only directly affect one table at a time. If you have foreign keys configured with `ON DELETE CASCADE` then child records will be deleted along with the parent record. Regardless of using cascade, you should have foreign keys on the table so that your `DELETE` doesn't leave orphaned child records with broken referential integrity.

Another way to achieve affecting other tables in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` is by using a trigger on the table. This can be desirable when you want to do checks before blindly deleting child records.